# How to read REST service that returns JSON object and store the same into PostgreSQL using Mule ESB, Mule Studio

Tags: json, postgresql, mule, mule-studio

So I have a REST based service which is hosted at

```
http://localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/567
```

If I query that, I get the result as:

```
{"JSONDataResult":"You requested product 567"}
```

I need to store the whole JSON data into a PostgreSQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE "JsonTable"
(
  "StoreJsonObject" json
)
```

If I want to parse the value field i.e. "You requested product 567", the program works (here I am using a different table whose column type is text):

```
<jdbc:postgresql-data-source name="PostgreSQL_Data_Source" user="username" password="pwd" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/TestDB" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="PostgreSQL Data Source"/>
<jdbc:connector name="PostgreSQL_Connector" dataSource-ref="PostgreSQL_Data_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database">
    <jdbc:query key="InsertRecord" value="INSERT INTO &quot;AnotherJSonTable&quot;(&quot;StoreJsonObject&quot;) VALUES (#[message.payload])"/>
</jdbc:connector>
<flow name="testRestFlow1" doc:name="testRestFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8082/index.html"  doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:rest-service-component httpMethod="GET" serviceUrl="http://localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/567">
    </http:rest-service-component>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <expression-transformer expression="#[message.payload.JSONDataResult]" doc:name="Expression"/>
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="InsertRecord" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="PostgreSQL_Connector" doc:name="Database"/>
</flow>
```

But how to store the entire JSON object ({"JSONDataResult":"You requested product 567"}).
What do I need to change in the "expression-transformer"?

If I do:

```
<jdbc:query key="InsertRecord" value="INSERT INTO &quot;JsonTable&quot;(&quot;StoreJsonObject&quot;) VALUES (#[message.payload])"/>

<expression-transformer expression="#[message.payload]" doc:name="Expression"/>
```

I receive exception:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No hstore extension installed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setMap(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1713)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setObject(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1916)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gStatement.setObject(AbstractJdbc3gStatement.java:36)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

INFO  2012-12-24 15:48:31,945 [[testrest].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: C:\Users\niladri.biswas\Desktop\input\all_winjs_ui_controls.txt
INFO  2012-12-24 15:48:31,945 [[testrest].testRestFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.transport.http.components.RestServiceWrapper: Invoking REST service: http://localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/567
ERROR 2012-12-24 15:48:31,992 [[testrest].PostgreSQL_Connector.dispatcher.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=jdbc://InsertRecord, connector=JdbcConnector
{
  name=PostgreSQL_Connector
  lifecycle=start
  this=15e7ea6
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=false
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[jdbc]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.jdbc.InsertRecord', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={queryTimeout=-1}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: LinkedHashMap
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also the record should be inserted only once after reading from the service and not multiple times.

Comment: Do you need to regularly fetch this JSON and insert it in DB? Or one time only? Or on demand?

Comment: @David Dossot, Sir I am very close to my target. If I want to read the value only and want to store it is happening(provided the table column should be text).But how to store the entire JSON response object? I have updated the question entirely.Please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to store the whole JSON, there is no need to deserialize it as an object: I suggest you simply transform the HTTP-streamed payload into a `java.lang.String` and insert it as-is in the DB.

This would done like that:

```
<jdbc:postgresql-data-source name="PostgreSQL_Data_Source"
    user="username" password="pwd" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/TestDB"
    transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="PostgreSQL Data Source" />

<jdbc:connector name="PostgreSQL_Connector" dataSource-ref="PostgreSQL_Data_Source"
    validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0"
    doc:name="Database">
    <jdbc:query key="InsertRecord"
        value="INSERT INTO &quot;AnotherJSonTable&quot;(&quot;StoreJsonObject&quot;) VALUES (CAST(#[message.payload] AS json))" />
</jdbc:connector>

<flow name="testRestFlow1" doc:name="testRestFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        address="http://localhost:8082/index.html" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <http:rest-service-component httpMethod="GET"
        serviceUrl="http://localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/567" />
    <object-to-string-transformer />
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
        queryKey="InsertRecord" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="PostgreSQL_Connector"
        doc:name="Database" />
</flow>
```

Comment: Hi, this works well if the column type is text. But my column type is JSon. And henceforth it is failing.ERROR: column "StoreJsonObject" is of type json but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 52(SQL Code: 0, SQL State: + 42804) (org.postgresql.util.PSQLException)
  org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl:2157 (null)

Comment: I,however, tried with VALUES (#[json:message.payload]).But in this case only blank row is getting inserted.What is wrong? and what will be the solution

Comment: You need to cast the payload to the JSON type either in the SQL expression with `... VALUES(CAST(#[message.payload] AS json))` or with a globally defined `character varying -> json` cast (see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createcast.html).

Comment: Thank you SIR for all your support. It has been solved now.Thanks a lot

Comment: Just 1 more thing to ask. Why cannot I directly cast from Object to JSON and from Object -> String -> JSON approach? If the first option is possible, can you please show me as how can I do so?

Comment: If you transform from JSON to Object in Mule the payload will become a `java.util.Map`, which will represent the JSON object coming from the remote HTTP endpoint. If you pass this `Map` payload directly to the JDBC outbound endpoint, JDBC will try to persist it as an serialized object in the database, which is not what you want. Dealing with `String`s only at Mule level avoids this problem.