# How to configure authentication using Mule?

Tags: authentication, mule, mule-studio

Basically it is an extension of my previous question: [How to read REST service that returns JSON object and store the same into PostgreSQL using Mule ESB, Mule Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003046/how-to-read-rest-service-that-returns-json-object-and-store-the-same-into-postgr/14024632#comment19412046_14024632)

I have some REST services being running at "http://localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/567"

Now in order to access those services, I need to authenticate as admin. The credentials are

**User Name**: admin

**Password:** pwd

The flow (existing) should be able to handle authentication & establish session via REST.

How to do authentication using Mule? The flow will stop if authentication fails. Else after successful authentication, it will read the REST service and will insert the data into PostgreSQL.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Configuring+Security)?

Comment: This link is for configuring inbound security: I have the impression the OP is looking for outbound (though not 100% sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the credentials in the outbound endpoint URI:

```
http://admin:pwd@localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/567
```

You can of course use properties to avoid hard-coding them in the Mule config:

```
http://${rest.admin.username}:${rest.admin.password}@localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/567
```

Comment: Did you mean to say in "http:rest-service-component" I should put?(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003046/how-to-read-rest-service-that-returns-json-object-and-store-the-same-into-postgr/14024632#comment19412046_14024632)

Comment: Yes use that in the service URL.