# MuleStudio 3.x: Is http:rest-service-component deprecated? Renamed? Replaced?

Tags: rest, mule, basic-authentication, mule-studio

Although there are matches for "rest" and "service" in the components pallet, those don't give you `<http:rest-service-component httpMethod="GET" serviceUrl="..." />`.

And if you manually add it to the XML, Mule Studio doesn't seem to know what to do with it.

Or perhaps it can't be a top level component in a flow?

What I'm trying to do:

- In a flow, call out to another web service
- Grab the resulting JSON and use it
- Use Basic Authentication; I've seen examples where include username/password in the URL itself
- The other service uses https

Perhaps it's no longer needed?  Maybe there's a more generic way to call other services and fetch data as part of a flow, maybe somehow using endpoints?

`http:rest-service-component` is still listed in the [Mule doc](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference), though they don't really show examples of it being used to fetch info.  Here are a [couple](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2080/using-mule-studio-to-read-data-from-rest-based-web-services-and-store) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003046/) that show it being used to fetch, although most examples I find on Google seem to talking about inbound connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a special component to call a REST service. It is just a normal HTTP call, so you can use `http:outbound-endpoint`. The `rest-service-component` wrapper provides very little additional value, so I think that's why it is generally not used.

Comment: Thanks, what I wound up with was <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="GET" doc:name="Call Service" address="https://my-company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json" contentType="application/json" mimeType="application/json" user="..." password="..." />, though still debugging, and I suspect I don't meed both contentType and mimType.

Comment: You probably have to put the username/password in the url.

Comment: YES, I was about to post again.  So even though the tag has user and password, you still have to stuff it into the URL... and I have to encode it due to punctuation. That seems really odd.  Do you know why that is???

Comment: I think the user and password params only work when you use host/port instead of address.